# Getting "replicated" values

Tags: sql

So I have two tables: Agent and Conta.

Agents can have a lot of Conta but one Conta can only have one Agent.

I want to display just the Agents, to create a html table where you can see all of the agents present in the database - on a backoffice!

I'm using the following code, but the result I'm getting is one agent entry for each conta where he participated.

```
WITH LAST_COUNT AS
   (SELECT {Conta}.[AgentId], {Conta}.[Data], {Conta}.[Valor],{Conta}.[Submit] 
    FROM {Conta})
SELECT
   {Agent}.[Id], {Agent}.[Nome], {Agent}.[Apelido], LAST_COUNT.[Data],
   LAST_COUNT.[Valor], LAST_COUNT.[Submit], {AgentPicture}.[Id],
   {AgentPicture}.[Filename], {Agent}.[Telemovel], {Agent}.[UserId]
FROM {Agent}
   LEFT JOIN {AgentPicture} ON {AgentPicture}.[Id] = {Agent}.[Id]
   INNER JOIN LAST_COUNT ON LAST_COUNT.[AgentId] = {Agent}.[Id]
WHERE {Agent}.[Id] LIKE '%' + @SearchFilter + '%'
   OR {Agent}.[Nome] LIKE '%' + @SearchFilter + '%'
   OR {Agent}.[Apelido] LIKE '%' + @SearchFilter + '%'
   OR @SearchFilter = ''
```

Can you help me? thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include the `CREATE TABLE` statements of your tables, some sample data for them, as `INSERT INTO` statements and the result the sample data should give. Also edit the tags and include the DBMS you are using.

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are joining Agent table with LAST_COUNT common table expression (CTE). As a result you have every record from Contra in your results.

Just remove

```
WITH LAST_COUNT AS
   (SELECT {Conta}.[AgentId], {Conta}.[Data], {Conta}.[Valor],{Conta}.[Submit] 
FROM {Conta})
```

from your query and drop the last JOIN statement: `LEFT JOIN LAST_COUNT ON LAST_COUNT.[AgentId] = {Agent}.[Id]`
Also, do not forget to remove the following columns, which are retrieved from LAST_COUNT table:

```
 LAST_COUNT.[Data],
   LAST_COUNT.[Valor], LAST_COUNT.[Submit],
```

Comment: Hi. While this might contain a solution to the problem of the OP, it is not a good answer, because it lacks explanation. Of course, the question it self also lives not up to SO standards as *sticky bit* pointed out. Still, you could largely improve the answer, if you'd explain what those statements he used are doing, and why they are counterproductive to his needs. Than this answer could help others as well and would move from "just apply this to solve your problem" to "just understand your problem and solve it" style.#